# How to paymentMetghodNounce from result from braintree in ios

Tags: ios, braintree

I am using braintree ios sdk and using their Drop in UI to add a customer card details. i am getting the UI successfully and after the customer submit the information, how can i get the paymentMEthodNounce from the result object. here is my code.

```
- (void)showDropIn:(NSString *)clientTokenOrTokenizationKey {
BTDropInRequest *request = [[BTDropInRequest alloc] init];
BTDropInController *dropIn = [[BTDropInController alloc] initWithAuthorization:clientTokenOrTokenizationKey request:request handler:^(BTDropInController * _Nonnull controller, BTDropInResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
    } else if (result.cancelled) {
        NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
    } else {

        // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
        // result.paymentOptionType
        // result.paymentMethod
        // result.paymentIcon
        // result.paymentDescription
    }
}];
[self presentViewController:dropIn animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

i think when the customer submit the result, payment nounce will be result object?? if it thinking is right how can get that nounce to a variable to send it to my server. i am fairly new in ios, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When open BTDropInController  after that you fill details like paypal.., and click pay button after that call delegate methods thats method provide nonce.

Answer (score 1):

For the new iOS v4 SDK I had to import Braintree also, I didn't have access to the `paymentMethod` property of the `BTDropInResult` otherwise.

```
import BraintreeDropIn
import Braintree
```

Answer (score 0):

**You implement BTDropInViewControllerDelegate to obtain the payment method nonce on success, and dismiss the Drop In UI in either case:**

```
- (void)dropInViewController:(__unused BTDropInViewController *)viewController didSucceedWithPaymentMethod:(BTPaymentMethod *)paymentMethod {
    [self postNonceToServer:paymentMethod.nonce]; // Send payment method nonce to your server
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)dropInViewControllerDidCancel:(__unused BTDropInViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Send payment method nonce to server**

```
- (void)postNonceToServer:(NSString *)paymentMethodNonce {
    // Update URL with your server
    NSURL *paymentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://your-server.example.com/checkout"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:paymentURL];
    request.HTTPBody = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"payment_method_nonce=%@", paymentMethodNonce] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // TODO: Handle success and failure
    }] resume];
}
```

Comment: But my confusion is still exists, that is i dont know where to add this code and how to get the nonce to varibale??

Comment: Which controller you are adding this -> BTDropInController ?

Comment: your controller name?

Answer (score 0):

```
BTDropInRequest *request = [[BTDropInRequest alloc] init];
request.amount = @"10";
BTDropInController *dropIn = [[BTDropInController alloc] initWithAuthorization:clientTokenOrTokenizationKey request:request handler:^(BTDropInController * _Nonnull controller, BTDropInResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
    } else if (result.cancelled) {
        NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
    } else {

        BTPaymentMethodNonce *selectedNonce = result.paymentMethod;
       [self postNonceToServer:self.selectedNonce.nonce];

    }
}];
[self presentViewController:dropIn animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: i got this error "value of type 'BTDropInResult' has no member 'paymentMethod'" when accessing result.paymentMethod.